# Does one need volatile and/or memory barrier with the following example using Interlocked.CompareExchange?

Tags: .net, multithreading

Please, observe:

```
private DateTime m_lastTimeUtc;
private int m_isInProgress;
...
if (DateTime.UtcNow - m_lastTimeUtc >= m_interval)
{
    if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref m_isInProgress, 1, 0) == 0)
    {
        if (DateTime.UtcNow - m_lastTimeUtc >= m_interval)
        {
            m_lastTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
            // Do the work
            m_lastTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
            Interlocked.Exchange(ref m_isInProgress, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

The intended semantics of this code is as follows:

- The code may be invoked frequently - hundreds of times a second.
- It should do certain work more or less periodically. If the code is not invoked too often then the actual period may be quite irregular, which is OK. But if it is invoked often (which is the case usually), then the work would be done pretty regularly.
- Threads which hit `m_isInProgress = 1` are going to skip the work and it is perfectly alright.

The environment is multithreaded, of course.

I have noticed people are using the `volatile` keyword and/or calling `Interlocked.MemoryBarrier()` when doing things similar to what I am doing here (or at least so it seems to me). I would be lying if I tell that I understand how both of them work.

Can someone explain whether I need them in my code and why?

P.S.

I have the same pattern repeating in a couple of places. So I want to introduce the following method:

```
private static void DoWork(TimeSpan interval, ref DateTime lastTimeUtc, ref int isInProgress, Action work)
{
    if (DateTime.UtcNow - lastTimeUtc >= interval && Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref isInProgress, 1, 0) == 0 && DateTime.UtcNow - lastTimeUtc >= interval)
    {
        lastTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
        work();
        lastTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref isInProgress, 0);
    }
}
```

Given this method, this is how I intend it to be invoked:

```
DoWork(m_interval, ref m_lastTimeUtc, ref m_isInProgress, () =>
{
  // Do the work
});
```

Would the answer be the same for `DoWork`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not need use `volatile` or memory barrier, because `Interlocked.CompareExchange` method implicitly generate full fences, which prevent instruction reordering and variable caching.

I recommend read this:

1. http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx
2. http://igoro.com/archive/volatile-keyword-in-c-memory-model-explained/